# Django rest framework get error message from response during a 400 Bad request

Tags: vue.js, django-rest-framework, axios

I'm currently running a Vue + DRF application. When something in the form is not up to par, and sent to the API, it returns a 400 Bad request as expected. Inspecting the response in the Network tab you get a clear validation error message, such as `{"zip_code":["This field must not be blank"]}`.

The question is, how can i extract this and display it in my Vue application? Trying to catch the error just returns `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 400 at eval` instead of the actual error message ("This field must not be blank").

The code patching looks something like:

```
axios.patch(`users/${this.$route.params.id}/`, this.user)
    .then(...)
    .catch(error => {...}) // get error message and display it frontend to user
```

Answer (score 6):

If anyone else has the same problem: using axios, you can get the error response body through `.catch(error => { console.log(error.response.data) }`.